# Change working directory in PHP doesn't affect HTML src

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php script in a folder "root/test/index.php" which calls another php script located in  "root/app/run.php"

In the run.php file I change the php's working directory with a call to chdir to simplify my require_once paths

All the php includes work fine, however HTML paths are totally messed up.

To make my style.css works I have to use a path relative to "root/test/" even if my style.css is in "root/app/".

This works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../app/style.css">
```

and that goes on for all HTML sources like img etc.

How can I change HTML working directory too?

I looked in php/HTML documentation, but I have find no good solution.
Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. Your CSS path is relative to the location. An option could be to use the absolute path and define a constant for that. See PHP 'define'

Comment: What do you mean for "location"? The place where my header.php and style.css are? In this case they both are in the same dir (root/app/). My run.php calls the header.php which refers to style.c . So, followig your reasonment, everything should works fine.

Comment: The path to your css is relative to the file where you include your header.php. Also remember that your HTML is acting from teh client side. the includes of PHP files arde acting on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML don't know anything about the working directory of your PHP script.

The HTML is sent to the client who can't know what was the working directory.

You could add some redirection in an .htaccess file (if you are using apache) to redirect `root/test/` to `root/app` or something like that.

Here is how it works :

1. You browser ask for /root/test/index.php
2. Your server handle all his things and then output HTML file
3. Your browser parse the HTML file

   1. If it find something like that  it will search the image here : /root/test/images/cat.png because you are viewing the /root/test/index.php file and you provide a relative path

Add a comment if you have more questions.

Comment: This means that HTML considers "root/test" the starting path? (Sorry. I may appear stupid, but I want to understand till the end.)

Comment: HTML doesn't consider anything. Your browser do.

Comment: I just add some explanations.

Comment: Ok. I got it. So with chdir I changed the working directory on the server, but the client is still sticked to the adresse of the page I visit (namely root/test/index.php) That's why you suggested me to use a redir... Thank you.